Notepad++ (how to insert text to specific line)
how do i insert or add a text to specific lines using notepad ++ for example
say i have this line :
<Additional_Population_Capacity>111</Additional_Population_Capacity>
now i want to add in another number inbetween the first and second "<Additional_Population_Capacity>" more specifically between the first ">" and the second "<" insert say a "2" so it either changes the value of the original "111" to a 2 or/and adds a 2 to the original value looking like "2111"
i learned a bit of what i can do with the Find and Replace features. i dont quite understand the Regular Expression feature tho. i also saw u can add to beginning and end of every line using "^" and "$" in Find, but i dont know if this is what i intend to do


Ctrl+H
Find what: <(Additional_Population_Capacity>)\K([^<]*)(?=</\1)
Replace with: 2$2  OR 2 alone depending on what you want on output
TICK Match case
TICK Wrap around
Search Mode Regular expression
UNTICK . matches newline
Replace all

Explanation:
<(Additional_Population_Capacity>)  # open tag, stored in group 1
\K                  # match reset operator, forget all we have seen until this position
([^<]*)             # group 2, 0 or more any character that is not <
(?=</\1)            # positive lookahead, make sure we have the close tag after.

Screenshot (before):

Screenshot (after):


i always like to ask is there a way to replace the numbers entirely only in between those > and < where the original number is? your answer helps in both. i am clarifying that i need to know how to add on (like u originally provided) and also how to replace,  but the original answer helps me tremondously tysm!
p.s. oh i think i see. just using 2 alone with the 2$2 replaces where only 2$2 adds on?

also can you tell me how to disable this feature: basically where ever i click it moves to that position. i dont know how to disable this feature if you could also help me with this i would be so grateful and thank you once again!

@Barak-YisraelBensamuel: You can't disable this feature.

@Barak-YisraelBensamuel: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, How to accept an answer
